# Does iptables -F permanently delete all iptables rules?

Tags: rhel, iptables

In a RHEL training document, the author says:

> ...run the following command to disable the firewall on the current system: **iptables -F**

He explicitly uses the word "disable" which to me suggests that it will be simple to re-enable.  In reading the man page though for iptables, I see this:

> Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given).  This is equivalent to **deleting** all the rules one by one.

Can I get clarification on the expected behavior?

Comment: Note that `iptables -F` flushes all the rules in the "filter" table, it doesn't flush the other tables (nat, mangle...) and doesn't restore the policies to their default, so they can't really be said to _disable the firewall_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `iptables` rules are stored in two places on Red Hat systems:

- In memory within the running kernel, where the firewall code checks them on network I/O. Flushing the rules with `iptables -F` gets rid of this ruleset only.
- In `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` from which they are loaded on boot. You can force a reload without rebooting with `service iptables reload` or `...restart`.

So the answer is no, flushing the rules with `iptables -F` is not permanent.

When you go into `setup` and modify the firewall rules, it saves them in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. You're not supposed to edit that file directly, but if you know the `iptables` command line format, you can pretty easily figure out the format of this file.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  I appreciate the detail and clarification.  Thanks Warren.

Answer (score 10):

Also, as a point of reference, here's how to flush ALL the current iptables rules:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
iptables=/sbin/iptables
$iptables -F
$iptables -X
$iptables -t nat -F
$iptables -t nat -X
$iptables -t mangle -F
$iptables -t mangle -X
$iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: There are actually more tables than that. At least `-t raw` and `-t security`. Instead of hard coding, use `/proc/net/ip_tables_names`